# how to get wifi csi (window or ubuntu)

Tags: wifi

I want get wifi csi information using naptop and draw graph liek picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZGGH.png). I use msi GE62 and Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168.
Someone say using intel 5300 nic.
If I must use intel 5300 nic, how can I connect intel 5300 nic outside naptop

Answer (score 0):

Not all NIC has the capability to extract CSI information. There are 2 ways that I know of, Intel 5300 or by using Atheros NIC (not all models, some of 9000 series are tested) This link can be helpful.

http://pdcc.ntu.edu.sg/wands/Atheros/

https://dhalperi.github.io/linux-80211n-csitool/

Comment: Do you know how to connect intel 5300 outside laptop?